# Multiple access of a function in meteor while using meteor call

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to access the collection names posts to check if the current user has already liked or not . If liked then showing liked button in different color.
The issue is the function is called two times.

```
  isLiked: function() {
let self = this;
console.log();
Meteor.call('posts.isLiked', self._id, (error, result) => {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}); 
}
```

The above function calls the posts.isLiked as below -

```
  'posts.isLiked': (_id) => {
    check(_id, String);

    if (!Meteor.user()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(401, 'You need to be signed in to continue');
    }
    if (!_id) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, '_id should not be blank');
    }

  return (Posts.find( { _id: _id , already_voted: { "$in" : [Meteor.userId()]} }).count() == 1);
}
```

The console shows output 2 times. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are using ES6 functions, you might be getting issue, to debug you application is the only solution, but can you use basic function call instead of ES6 speicfications?

below is what I am trying to ask you:

```
  isLiked: function() {
        let self = this;
        console.log();
        Meteor.call('posts.isLiked', self._id, function(error, result) {
           console.log(result);
           return result;
        }); 
  }

  'posts.isLiked': function(_id){
    check(_id, String);

    if (!Meteor.user()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(401, 'You need to be signed in to continue');
    }
    if (!_id) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, '_id should not be blank');
    }

  return (Posts.find( { _id: _id , already_voted: { "$in" : [Meteor.userId()]} }).count() == 1);
}
```

Also put a console log at first line of ***isLiked*** so that you will know that Meteor.call is not called twice, but, may be ***isLiked*** is getting called twice.

Comment: isLiked is called two times therefore meteor call is also called two times.

Comment: So, how can we help now? we don't have your code, what you are doing? why called two times?

Comment: In Html part I am using it with  {{# if isLiked}}